# Finding a simple pattern in a string unless escaped

Tags: java, regex

I have some code that looks for a simple bold markup

```
private Pattern bold = Pattern.compile("\\*[^\\*]*\\*")
```

If someone uses: this my *bolded* text - my pattern would find "bolded"

I now need a way to use * not in the context of bolding.  So I'd like to allow escaping.

E.g. this my \*non-bolded\* text - should not find any pattern.

Is there a simple way I can change my Regex to achieve this?

Comment: Add a negative lookbehind to the first `*`, this way it will skip any escaped `*`. You don't need to escape `*` in a character group. You should use a possestive matcher. So `(?>!\\\\)\\*[^*]++\\*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a negative lookbehind here:

```
(?<!\\)\*[^*]+(?<!\\)\*
```

In a Java string, this gives (backslash galore):

```
"(?<!\\\\)\\*[^*]+(?<!\\\\)\\*"
```

Note: the star (`*`) has no special meaning within a character class, therefore there is no need to escape it

Note 2: `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind; it is an anchor, which means it finds a *position* but consumes no text. Literally, it can be translated as: "find a position where there is no *preceding text* matching regex `...`". Other anchors are:

- `^`: find a position where there is no available input before (ie, can only match at the beginning of the input);
- `$`: find a position where there is no available input after (ie, can only match at the end of the input);
- `(?=...)`: find a position where the following text matches regex `...` (this is called a positive lookahead);
- `(?!...)`: find a position where the following text *does not* match regex `...` (this is called a negative lookahead);
- `(?<=...)`: find a position where the preceding text matches regex `...` (this is a positive lookbehind);
- `\<`: find a position where the preceding input is either nothing or a character which is not a word character, and the following character is a word character (implementation dependent);
- `\>`: find a position where the following input is either nothing or a character which is not a word character, and the preceding character is a word character (implementation dependent);
- `\b`: either `\<` or `\>`.

Note 3: Javascript regexes do not support lookbehinds; neither do they support `\<` or `\>`. More information [here](http://regular-expressions.info).

Note 4: with some regex engines, it is possible to alter the meaning of `^` and `$` to match positions at the beginning and end of *each line* instead; in Java, that is `Pattern.MULTILINE`; in Perl-like regex engines, that is `/m`.

Comment: Missing ending asterisk: (?<!\\)\*[^*]+\*(?<!\\)

Comment: @greuze oops... Good spotting!

Comment: @BruceLowe good to know! Hope you did not get lost with the rest of the post... But, mind, this is important as well

Comment: @FGE Nope - you managed to make a fairly complex topic quite easy to understand.  I have to use this in a number of regex's and extracted the principals you have taught me quite easily. Many Thanks for this.

Comment: @BruceLowe good to know! I have to thank you for your feedback here. Regexes are, ultimately, a collection of simple concepts, it is just that tearing regexes apart to basic concepts is not that easy ;)

Comment: Nice answer, but doesn't work when escaped asterisk are in the bolded text: "My \*bold \\* text\*" should return "bold \\* text"

Comment: @greuze not sure this is what the op wants?

Comment: @fge Yes, thay point is not clear in the question... In any case, you way only allows to escape asterisk out a bolded text, my answer works in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

This negative lookbehind based regex should work for you:

```
(?<!\\)\*[^*]+\*(?<!\\)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/sobKUrkTjP

When translated to Java it will become:

```
(?<!\\\\)\\*[^*]+\\*(?<!\\\\)
```

Comment: Rubular has this disadvantage that if the regex does not conform to what Ruby expects, you're doomed... Note that I don't blame Ruby at all, I just say that some interpretations are not in accordance with other regex engines. Consider for instance that `\w` only matches ASCII in Java (yes! Unfortunate but htis is true!). I won't blame you however: no current existing site handles _all_ regex engines.

Comment: This expression: "My *bold \* text*" should obtain "bold \* text", but don't with your example in rubular

Comment: @greuze: Pls the the OP again. BOlded text needs to be wrapped in asterisks like this: `My *bold text*`

Comment: @anubhava Sorry about the typing, the text was modified by stackoverflow using markup... I wrote "My \*bold \\* text*" should obtain "bold \* text".

Comment: @anubhava Yes I did and it didn't work. Here is the example: http://www.rubular.com/r/fYKW2O8rH1

Comment: @greuze: In that case I guess you should post this comment on accepted answer as my answer wasn't accepted by OP :P

Answer (score 1):

I think the two answers until now are very interesting, but not completely correct. They don't work when a bolded text has escaped asterisk inside (I assume this is almost the main reason to escape asterisks).

For example:

> My *bold \*text* here, another *bold*, more \* and *here\* and
>   \* end* more text

Should find three groups:

> *bold \*text*
>
> *bold*
>
> *here\* and \* end*

With a little modification, we can do that, with this regular expression:

```
(?<!\\)\*([^*\\]|\\\*)+\*
```

can be tested here:
http://www.rubular.com/r/Jeml02HHYJ

Of course, in Java some more escaping is needed:

```
(?<!\\\\)\\*([^*\\\\]|\\\\\\*)+\\*
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'll see if I can modify my regex accordingly